# How to get the list of objects into the correct JSON format?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I run a query that returns me a list of customers orders:

```
SELECT cust_no, cust_name, order_no, order_name FROM CustomerOrders
```

In my `Controller Action` method, I do the following (`_context` is my `DataContext`):

```
var results = _context.CustomerOrders.ToList();

return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

When I inspect this in the debugger, I see the list of objects, but not being too familiar with Json, I am not sure how this would look when it as a Json string. The format I want is:

```
{
    "Customer": {
        "cust_no": "123",
        "cust_name": "john",
        "Orders": [
            {
                "order_no": "1",
                "order_name": "order1"
            },
            {
                "order_no": "2",
                "order_name": "order2"
            }
        ]
     },
     "Customer": {
         "cust_no": "456",
         "cust_name": "jane",
         "Orders": [
            {
                "order_no": "3",
                "order_name": "order3"
            },
            {
                "order_no": "4",
                "order_name": "order4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I currently can get into this:

`{ Customer = "123", cust_name = "John", Orders = "1", oder_no = "order1" }`

with:

```
_context.CustomerOrders.Select(x => new 
                                    {
                                        Customer= x.cust_no, x.cust_name, 
                                        Orders = x.order_no, x.order_name});

public ActionResult GetCustomerOrders()
    {
        JsonResult result = null;
        try
        {
            var results = new {Customers = _context.CustomerOrders.ToList()};

            return Json(results,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have JSON key-value pairs with the same key at the same level of nesting (in your case level 0).  If you want, you can return an anonymous type by doing something like:

```
var results = new {Customers = _context.CustomerOrders.ToList()};
```

**NOTE** - Forgot to add that the above code will look like:

```
{
    Customers: [{
        "cust_no": "123",
            "cust_name": "john",
            "Orders": [{
            "order_no": "1",
                "order_name": "order1"
        }, {
            "order_no": "2",
                "order_name": "order2"
        }]
    }, {
        "cust_no": "456",
            "cust_name": "jane",
            "Orders": [{
            "order_no": "3",
                "order_name": "order3"
        }, {
            "order_no": "4",
                "order_name": "order4"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Check the specification for JSON here: http://www.json.org/

**EDIT - (in response to fixing your Linq Query)** 
The following is what you need:

```
    var results = (from co in _context.CustomerOrders
                   group co by new { co.cust_no, co.cust_name } into orders
                   select new
                   {
                       Customer = new
                       {
                           cust_name = orders.Key.cust_name,
                           cust_no = orders.Key.cust_no,
                           Orders = orders.Select(o=> new{o.order_name,o.order_no })
                       }
                   }).AsEnumerable();
    return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The results using mock data should look like the following:

```
[{
    "Customer": {
        "cust_name": "ted",
        "cust_no": "1441865486",
        "Orders": [{
            "order_name": "ted1271196444",
            "order_no": "1877898370"
        }, {
            "order_name": "ted1137404580",
            "order_no": "1033969821"
        }, {
            "order_name": "ted113580415",
            "order_no": "844051358"
        }, {
            "order_name": "ted842422359",
            "order_no": "1063097922"
        }, {
            "order_name": "ted2140579126",
            "order_no": "1170215299"
        }, {
            "order_name": "ted843928549",
            "order_no": "2143378901"
        }]
    }
}, {
    "Customer": {
        "cust_name": "Jack",
        "cust_no": "1258770771",
        "Orders": [{
            "order_name": "Jack879867938",
            "order_no": "585569719"
        }, {
            "order_name": "Jack1423388998",
            "order_no": "209013154"
        }]
    }
}, {
    "Customer": {
        "cust_name": "joe",
        "cust_no": "1223478754",
        "Orders": [{
            "order_name": "joe1283306017",
            "order_no": "1305330220"
        }, {
            "order_name": "joe1369830458",
            "order_no": "1996259538"
        }, {
            "order_name": "joe1772918032",
            "order_no": "1265675292"
        }, {
            "order_name": "joe535974281",
            "order_no": "837890619"
        }, {
            "order_name": "joe194556914",
            "order_no": "812224857"
        }, {
            "order_name": "joe28812423",
            "order_no": "515669909"
        }, {
            "order_name": "joe2004245093",
            "order_no": "1634742463"
        }]
    }
}, {
    "Customer": {
        "cust_name": "jill",
        "cust_no": "659748358",
        "Orders": [{
            "order_name": "jill1462582377",
            "order_no": "1817173079"
        }, {
            "order_name": "jill1848627650",
            "order_no": "830495643"
        }, {
            "order_name": "jill727215465",
            "order_no": "728808273"
        }, {
            "order_name": "jill1071911623",
            "order_no": "824043403"
        }, {
            "order_name": "jill126843849",
            "order_no": "1654825240"
        }]
    }
}]
```

Comment: How did you inspect what the JSON string would look like?  When I do: `result = Json(new {Customers = _context.CustomerOrders.ToList()},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`, I just see a list of objects, not the formatted JSOn string.

Comment: I am not seeing the JSON string in the Data property when I step into the method. I just see a list of objects.  I will post my complete method.

Comment: @Xaisoft You can see the string representation of your object by navigating to the URL of your controller action that returns the JSON.  I would use Firefox or Chrome.  I *think* IE will want you to download it if you navifate to it.

Comment: The JSON string will be seen on the client side of your browser.

Comment: Ok, one thing I must point out is that I am using LINQ to Entities, so I am getting a bunch of extra linq to entity properties coming back.  Also, I don't see Orders, I just see Customers and their orders in them.  I need it to be grouped by cust_no, essentially a list of Customer objects and each Customer object has an array of orders.

Comment: So, your issue is now on how you construct your Linq query.  See my edit above.

Comment: Cool, I got it to work yesterday, so is the only way to do it is through the query syntax or can it be done through lambda syntax. Thanks.

Comment: @Xaisoft Yes.  You should finalize and implement your data structure before pushing it into it JSON format.  As you can see, I generated my link to match your expected data structure.